# Using PHP timestamp in Javascript Script

Tags: javascript, php

I have HTML canvas clock that I'm trying to get timezone to work on without using a library. Clock doesn't have to always be exact since the page is constantly refreshed. The clock works fine using client time.

I basically have the code on [this page](https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/tryit.asp?filename=trycanvas_clock_start) for the clock.

Using PHP:

```
<?php date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles'); ?>
```

Javascript:

```
var timestamp = new Date(<?php echo date("Y m d H:i:s") * 1000; ?>);
```

Also tried:

```
var timestamp = new Date(<?php echo time() * 1000 ?>);
```

Clock either points at 12:00 or some fixed time. The clock updates every second without the PHP echo.

UPDATE: I've read others on SE point out that the above scripts work for them, but I can't get them to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use straight up JavaScript? There's no need to use timezones, because it points immediately to the timezone (I believe set on the computer itself). If you find it hard to work with, use [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/); it makes it a LOT easier to use than formatting it yourself.

If you MUST use timezones, Moment.js includes [that](https://momentjs.com/timezone) too.

Comment: ended up using Moment timezone

Answer (score 0):

In ES6+ you can extend *Date* as your own class and teach it how to do things, e.g. add methods to change the *timezone offset* and change how methods such as *toString* work

```
class CustomDate extends Date {
    constructor(...args) {
        super(...args);
        this.offset = (new Date()).getTimezoneOffset();
        this.zone = null;
    }
    getTimezoneOffset() {
        return this.offset;
    }
    setTimezoneOffset(zoneOffset, zoneName = null) {
        this.offset = zoneOffset;
        this.zone = zoneName;
    }
    getAdjustedDate() {
        const time = super.getTime() - (this.offset * 60 * 1000);
        return new Date(time);
    }
    toString() {
        const date =this.getAdjustedDate();
        const delta = Math.abs(this.offset);
        const hh = ('00' + Math.floor(delta / 60)).slice(-2);
        const mm = ('00' + Math.floor((delta % 60))).slice(-2);

        const offset = (this.offset > 0 ? '-' : '+')
            + hh + ':' + mm
            + (this.zone ? ' (' + this.zone + ')' : '');

        return date.toISOString().slice(0, -1)
            + (this.offset === 0 ? 'Z' : offset);
    }
}
```

Then

```
const customDate = new CustomDate();
customDate.setTimezoneOffset(5 * 60); // 5 hours behind UTC
customDate.toString(); // "2017-07-15T20:28:35.699-05:00"
```

Comment: The offset still relies on client time doesn't it? Like if I change my time on my computer, the script's time output will be different. I.E., it's 12pm pacific and I set my offset to eastern time. If I change my time to 10am, the eastern time clock will also change 2 hours back.

Comment: Defaults to client timezone, but `.toString` is calculated by adjusting UTC by the timezone offset, then using UTC date values at that adjusted UTC time

Comment: i.e. 1. you specify the offset from UTC you want with `setTimezoneOffset`, 2. use `getAdjustedDate` to get a date which has it's UTC time adjusted by the timezone offset, 3. then you use UTC-methods to get the local time at that timezone. (steps 2 and 3 are both done in the `toString` example above)